# Probability - Student passing a test

Tags: probability

A student needs to answer at least 3 out of 4 questions correctly in order to pass a test. The questions are chosen at random from a collection of 40 questions, 30 of which the student knows the answer to.

How do I calculate the probability of something like this?

EDIT:
My initial approach

I tried modeling this as an urn consisting of 30 blue and 10 red balls. Then drawing 4 balls from that urn, what would be the probability of getting at least 3 blue balls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He can get all 4 right.  How  many ways to choose 4 question from the set of 30 that he knows the answer to?

Or, he can get 3 right and one wrong.  How many ways to choose 3 from a set of 30 plus 1 from a set of 10.

All divided by the number or ways to choose 4 questions for the test.

Comment: so ((30 nCr 4) + (30 nCr 3) + (10 nCr 1))/(40 nCr 4) = ~ 0.34 ?

Comment: $\frac {{30\choose 4} + {30\choose 3}{10\choose 1}}{{40\choose 4}} \approx 74.4\%$